# Square free proof on if $b|a^2$ then $b|a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

We say that b is square-free if $b$ can be written as the product of distinct prime factors.
That is, $b = p_1 \dotsm p_n$ for $p_1$ does not equal $p_2$ which does not equal $\dotsc p_n$
Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that if b is square-free and $b|a^2$ then $b|a$.

My understanding is that we use a proof similar to if $b|a$ then $b|a^2$, however, I don't understand how to use that proof to prove it's converse.

Sorry in advanced for the format I am still learning how to use it since I just started using the site, if anyone can help me reformat it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that we use a proof similar to if b|a then b|a^2,

Not really.  If $b|a$ then there exist an integer $k$ so that $a = bk$.  So that mean $a^2 = (bk)^2 = b(bk^2)$ and as $bk^2$ is an integer, $b|a$.

But the converse need not be true at all.  That $9|6^2$.  That is $6^2 = 36$ and $9\cdot 4 = 36$ so $9\mid 6^2$.  But we do not have $9\mid 6$.

The reason this fails is that some of the prime factors $9$ may be squared and one single power of it may divide $6$ and the other divides $6$ so $9 =3\cdot 3$ and $3|6$ so $3^2 |6^2 but we don't have $3^2|6$.

But if $b$ is squarefree there and every factor of $b\mid a^2$ then as $b$ only has single power factors each factor can't be split among the two two $a$s whose product make $a^2$.

Now to state that *formally* and without mushy handwaving speak....

For any prime factor, $p$ of $b$ we know that $p|a^2$.  SO by Euclid's Lemma $p|a$.  SO $(\prod_{p|a} p)\mid a$.  But as $b$ is square free $b= \prod_{p|a} p$.  And $b|a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a =p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_r^{k_r}$, so that $a^2 =p_1^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}\dots p_r^{2k_r}$. If $d$ is any divisor of $a^2$ then $d = p_1^{m_1}p_2^{m_2}\dots p_r^{m_r}$, where for each $i$, $m_i\in \{0,1,\dots , 2k_i\}$.

In particular, any square-free divisor forces $m_i$ to be in $\{0,1\}$ and you are done.